# Problema con getHighestColumn() PHPExcel

Tags: php

Estoy teniendo un problema, tengo que hacer un for y la variable que me pasa es de la libreria `PHPExcel ->getHighestColumn()`, pero el problema es que me devuelve "G", "Z", "AA", "AB". Y ahí esta el problema, se me ocurrió pasarlo a ASCII (A es 65, B es 66, etc) pero cuando quiero pasar a ascii el valor de la columna AA o AB por ejemplo (con la función `ord()`) me devuelve 65, como si el valor fuera A, y no AA o AB. Espero si alguno tiene idea como hacerlo. Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Sería muy bueno que añadieras una sección de código con las pruebas que hiciste para poder ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 1):

Para lograr hacer lo que quieres puedes usar la función `columnIndexFromString()` que ofrece PHPExcel. Por ejemplo:

```
$colNumber = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($colString);
```

Donde $colString es la letra de la columna, es decir: retorna 1 con `$colString = 'A'`, 26 con 'Z', 27 con 'AA', etc.

Puedes leer más info en la siguiente pregunta de SO en inglés:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564155/how-to-get-the-number-of-columns-of-worksheet-as-integer-28-instead-of-excel-l